# Скрипт не работает в Опере и на мобильных

Tags: javascript, opera

Есть скрипт, который разворачивает длинные списки по клику, все работает с хроме и мозилле, но не работает в Опере и на мобильных браузерах.В чем может быть причина?

**UPD.** добавляю HTML

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#bPrices').on('click', '.js-menu-price', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        
        var id  = $(this).attr('href'),
            top = $(id).offset().top;
            
        $('body,html').animate({scrollTop: top}, 700);
    });

 $('#bPrices .js-show-prices').on('click', function(){
  var $this = $(this),
   $block = $this.closest('.all_price').prev('.price-table'),
   $btnHide = $this.next('.js-hide-prices');
   
  $block.find('.hide-price').fadeIn();
  $this.hide();
  $btnHide.show();
  
  return false;
 });
 
 $('#bPrices .js-hide-prices').on('click', function(){
  var $this = $(this),
   $block = $this.closest('.all_price').prev('.price-table'),
   $btnShow = $this.prev('.js-show-prices');
   
  $block.find('.hide-price').fadeOut();
  $this.hide();
  $btnShow.show();
  
  return false;
 });
 
 $('#bPrices .mobile-price').on('click', function(){
     $('#bPrices .left_col').slideToggle();
    }); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="bPrices" class="all_content">
  <span class="mobile-price">Услуги </span>
  <div class="right_col">
    <div class="b-price-text">
      <div id="bx_incl_area_8_1_2">Из-за большого объёма информации иногда цены на сайте могут не соответствовать, обратитесь к администратору для уточнения.</div>
    </div>

    <h2 id="allergolog-immunolog">Аллерголог-иммунолог</h2>

    <table class="price-table">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Прием лечебно-диагностический врача аллерголога-иммунолога первичный (осмотр, консультация)</td>
          <td><span>1800</span> руб</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Прием лечебно-диагностический аллерголога-иммунолога повторный (осмотр, консультация)</td>
          <td>
            <span>1600</span> руб
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Прием врача аллерголога-иммунолога по результатам обследования / диспансерный</td>
          <td>
            <span>1200</span> руб
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Проведение кожных проб (1 тест)</td>
          <td>
            <span>450</span> руб
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="hide-price" style="display: table-row;">
          <td>Проведение кожного скарификационного теста</td>
          <td>
            <span>500</span> руб
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="hide-price" style="display: table-row;">
          <td>Провокационные аллергологические тесты (назальный, конъюнктивальный)</td>
          <td>
            <span>1200</span> руб
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="hide-price" style="display: table-row;">
          <td>Курс СЛИТ, Антиполлин</td>
          <td>
            <span>17000</span> руб
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="hide-price" style="display: table-row;">
          <td>Аллерген-специфическая иммунотерапия (одна инъекция)</td>
          <td>
            <span>4500</span> руб
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="hide-price" style="display: table-row;">
          <td>Лечение аллергических заболеваний инъекционным препаратом Рузам</td>
          <td>
            <span>2900</span> руб
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <div class="all_price">
      <a href="javascript:" class="js-show-prices" style="display: none;">Показать все цены</a>
      <a href="javascript:" class="js-hide-prices" style="display: inline;">Скрыть список</a>
    </div>
    <div class="line"></div>
  </div>
```

upd2. добавляю php

```
<table class="price-table">
                        <?foreach($arSection['ITEMS'] as $key => $arItem):
                            $num = $key + 1;
                            $showElemCnt = intval($arSection['UF_SHOW_ELEM']);
                        ?>
                            <tr<?if($showElemCnt < $num):?> class="hide-price"<?endif;?>>
                                <td><?=strip_tags($arItem['PREVIEW_TEXT']);?></td>
                                <td>
                                    <?if($arItem['PROPERTY_PRICE_VALUE']):?>
                                        <span><?=$arItem['PROPERTY_PRICE_VALUE'];?></span> руб
                                    <?else:?>
                                        <span>—</span>
                                    <?endif;?>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        <?endforeach;?>
                    </table>

                    <?if($showElemCnt < count($arSection['ITEMS'])):?>
                        <div class="all_price">
                            <a href="javascript:" class="js-show-prices">Показать все цены</a>
                            <a href="javascript:" class="js-hide-prices">Скрыть список</a>
                        </div>
                    <?endif;?>
```

Comment: что конкретно не работает? У вас 4 клика какой из них не работает?

Comment: На странице есть длинный прайс, по умолчанию показывается только небольшая часть, при клике на  js-show-prices должен разворачиваться прайс полностью и смениться на js-hide-prices, при клике на который прайс опять свернется до исходного положения. Так работает в хроме и мозилле

Comment: а что такое .mobile-price ?

Comment: не знаю, я пробовал эти 2 строчки полностью убрать, но изменений никаких не увидел
upd. сейас увидел, там есть один span с классом mobile-price, но он сейчас пустой

Comment: а js-hide-prices появляется при клике?

Comment: нет, вообще никакой реакции при клике

Comment: добавьте, плиз, html к этим кнопкам

Comment: добавил............

Comment: Получается что в таблице начиная с 5 строки добавлен класс hide-price, а при клике на Показать все цены, он удаляется, но почему то это не происходит в опере и на моб

Comment: нет, он не удаляется

Comment: а на сайте удаляется, добавил еще php код

Comment: @VitaliyAntal если выполнить данный снипет в Опере то он отработает

Comment: в вопросе нет кода, который удаляет у каких-либо элементов класс `"hide-price"`

Comment: добавляет к этим классам display:none

Comment: Отключил в настройках Битрикса "Подключать минифицированные версии CSS и JS файлов" и все заработало.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отключил в настройках Битрикса:

> "Подключать минифицированные версии CSS и JS файлов"

и все заработало